# how to recover 10 days back data in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

how to recover data of deleted files in Ubuntu, i have tried test-disk to recover my file but the file is empty so it will be good to recover 10 days back data to restore it

Comment: if you dont have a backup, the file is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try photorec, not Testdisk.  Photorec will look at the raw data, and if it recognises it by signature it will recover it into a generic name. If you have a good idea of the content of the deleted file you can grep for it I'm the recovered file to greatly narrow the number of files to look through.

You have not indicated what file system you are trying to recover data from. If it's an ext3/4 filesystem try using ext4undelete. Note that if the file you want to recover is on the same file system as the OS you should use a boot disk so as not to write more data to the disk which further reduces the chance of recovery.  This won't work of your partition is xfs based.